# Errors with enterprise library logging while multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, enterprise-library

I'm problems while trying to use the Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging inside of a new thread.  Here is the code i use to start the thread:

```
Thread cleanupThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DirectoryCleanup));
cleanupThread.Start();
```

Inside the DirectoryCleanup method an error is thrown on the following line:

```
Logger.Write(ex.Message, "General", 100, 0, 
System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Critical);
```

And here is the error I get:

```
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger' 
threw an exception.
```

Here is the inner Exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}
```

The logger works just fine in the main thread of the program.  It only has problems with the new thread.  I've spent a lot of time searching but I can't seem to find an answer.
Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

I tried to use the thread pool using the following code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(DirectoryCleanup);
```

It produced the same error as above.

Comment: Is there a reason you create your own thread? Do you experience the same problem when using a thread from the threadpool? ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...)

Comment: I'm new to threading.  Just learning how to use it.  I haven't used the thread pool much yet.  I'll will try that to see if it makes any difference.  Even if my current method will not work, I would still like to understand why it didn't work.

Comment: As @bitbonk said. The error should be impossible since the thread is running in the same appdomain? Hence if the logging works in the main thread it should also work in the other thread. A dll (`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common`) is either loaded in the appdomain or it's not. You either got the error wrong, or doing something really wierd ;)

Comment: im also quite new to threading, but its worth a try. =).

Comment: I agree that it should work because everything is in the same appdomain.  It is a strange error, which is why I asked the question.  Is there any additional information that I could provide that would help to shed some light onto what the issue is?